# Is there a possibility of nesting tab navigator inside a drawer navigator in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer, react-native-tabnavigator

Is there a possibility of nesting tab navigator inside a drawer navigator in react-native? when the hamburger menu icon is invoked,I want the drawer to cover the entire screen and implement Tab navigator inside of it. I need some help with this.

Comment: Where do you want exactly implement Tab navigator?

Comment: Hi. I want to implement the Tab navigator inside the drawer.

Comment: https://reactnativecode.com/show-tab-navigator-inside-drawer-navigator/ . does this help?

Answer (score 0):

To cover the entire screen you can set the `drawerWidth` to be the width of the screen. see [how to get the screen width](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions) in react native documentation

You can use the `contentComponent` to render the tab navigator:

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer'
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native'

import MyTabNavigator from 'path-to-my-tab-navigator'

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window')

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    ... // screens 
  },
  {
    drawerWidth: width
    contentComponent: MyTabNavigator
  }
)
```

See the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. Firstly, I couldn't set **Tab Navigation** inside **Drawer Navigation**.

For that I used "*React Native Tab View*" you can install it from "https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tab-view", its worked with me.

```
<Drawer.Navigator
  drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerComp {...props} />}>
  <Drawer.Screen name="MainStack" component={MainStack} />
</Drawer.Navigator>


export const CustomDrawerComp = (props) => {
  const {navigation} = props;
  const layout = useWindowDimensions();

  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const [routes] = React.useState([
    { key: 'first', title: 'FIRST' },
    { key: 'second', title: 'SECOND' },
  ]);

  return (
    <TabView
      navigationState={{ index, routes }}
      renderScene={SceneMap({
        first: FirstTab,   << Add first tab view
        second: SecondTab,   << Add second tab view
      })}
      onIndexChange={setIndex}
      initialLayout={{ width: layout.width }}
      />
  );
};
```

Also, You might get a simple error after used it "*Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCViewPager" was not found in the UIManager*" it's very easy don't worry, You can solve it from "https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/issues/1050"

I hope that helping some one.

[Image Tabs inside Drawer Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1Yri.png)